# Gulp custom validation on CSS and SASS files

Tags: css, sass, gulp

Using [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) I have created a simple streamline which validates my CSS and SASS files using [csslint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-csslint).
Is it somehow possible to apply custom validation conditional logic?
For instance, on my SASS files I would like to avoid using nested rules up to 2 levels.

```
/* valid rule */
.div
    .div
        color: red

/* invalid rule */
.div
    .div
        a
            color: green
```

On cases like these my streamline should output the errors on te console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should switch from CSS validation to SASS validation. A good example would be using gulp-scss-lint which has a bigger flexibility on validation configuration.

The configuration parameters are available [here](https://github.com/causes/scss-lint/blob/master/config/default.yml). At line `89` you can see that you can limit the nesting depth.

Hope this helps.